# Select first element of dropdown of an input box

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input box

```
<input id="source" onchange="openDropdown(...)" >
```

Whenever I enter any text inside this input box a dropdown of suggestion appears. Now I want to automatically select the first suggestion using JavaScript, but can't find any way to do this.
REQUIREMENT: You need to only use input id to select the first suggestion. I don't know the onchange function.

> NOTE:- I am not having any select element here.I am just having an
>   input element here.So the thing is that i just want to select the
>   first element in the dropdown which will open after we start typing in
>   that input box(& i don't know how this dropdown is coming.I just know
>   that some input box is there.)I am not having the full code.

Comment: You are using a lookup, so more code will be needed to answer this question

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#source") .change(function () {             
  var abc = $('option:first-child',this) .text();
```

Please try this .Hope this will help You..

Answer (score 0):

try this code,By default I select option 3 but you can change it

```js
function openDropdown(){

  $("#lst option:first").prop("selected","selected")
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="source" onchange="openDropdown()" >

<select id="lst">
  <option value=1>option 1</option>
   <option value=2>option 2</option>
   <option value=3 selected>option 3</option>
   <option value=4>option 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I am not having any select element here.I am just having an input element here.So the thing is that i just want to select the first element in the dropdown which will open after we start typing in that input box(& i don't know how this dropdown is coming.I just know that some input box is there.)I am not having the full code.

Comment: are you using any library ie: jQuery UI